# Find minimum value of $n$ with real sequence numbers $ x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n $

Tags: sequences-and-series, real-numbers

For the real sequence numbers $ x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n $ are satisfied:

1. the sum of any 7 elements of the sequence is always less than 15,
2. The sum of $ n $ elements is exactly 100.
   Find minimum value of $n$?

I find $x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_{50} =2$ satisfy this problems, but I can't to show that it's minimun value of $n$.

Answer (score 2):

What about $n=47$, and $x_1,x_2,...= \frac{100}{47}$ ?

If $n = 46$, the average of the terms is $\frac{100}{46}$, and any $7$ of them would have a sum greater than $15$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "some 7" instead of "any 7"?